# Use cases where an administrator has complete autonomy to change a username

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, security, database-design, socket.io

We are developing a WebRTC application having three components:

- android (assistant glass device)
- server (nodejs backend)
- webapp (reactjs frontend)

This enables two-way communication between the glass device and the webapp for a healthcare application. One of the requirements allows the administrator having the highest role to edit the username of any user across organizations.

As a backend developer, I found this requirement to be odd since I've not come across any such app. For implementing the call feature we've used an in-memory map `username` -> `socketId` for one / many organizations as a pilot version.

There are problems in the case where two users are on a call and the administrator--knowingly or unknowingly--changes the username for either side but the server can update the socket only if the username is the same as the previous PING event from the client. (We're using socket.io):

1. A user who disconnects may not be able to reconnect to their earlier active video call if their username gets changed since the server has no way of checking this.
2. Code to handle the case of updating a user is redundant since there is a UNIQUE constraint.

I am willing to refactor the code to map the socket with `userId -> socketId`, but eventually this will be stored in the DB with unnecessary R/W operations.

Username should be uneditable irrespective of role of a user.

What are some design patterns to follow in order to address the issue of granularly restricting users to change username according to their associated role?

Comment: Many systems that have a username concept will allow it to be changed (including StackOverflow itself), allowing other users to change it is, at best, an exceptional feature.  That said, this is venturing into a design and opinionated decision, and not one we can answer for you.

Comment: This is too vague. What is "this issue"? The sentence before the bullets is contorted. Once clear & organized: How are you stuck designing/coding? "Please don't ask us to do your research & evaluation for you." [research effort expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
[“help me” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)
[asking "best practice" a bad thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[“Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) ["shopping list"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/266284)

Comment: Edited again. It seems my original wording was confusing.

Comment: Ok, I give up. I implemented all the suggested changes - still I get a message saying that the edits were unsuccessful in reopening the question. That’s it, no offense taken - probably it’s just my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could schedule the username change as follows:

- you could create a table or something where you store scheduled username changes
- whenever an activity (a call or something) finishes, the system would check whether there are any more activities remaining. If so, then do nothing. Otherwise, the username would be changed and the schedule would be removed
- new activities could not be started by the user while this transitioning time still applies
- optionally a maximum wait time could be applied, so, if the user still has an activity after 2 hours (or the maximum time of your preference), then the username would be changed no matter what
- the admin would have a choice for scheduling such a change or doing it instantly

This way the username and your in-memory mapping would work until the user finishes his/her activities, unless the admin chooses to perform the change instantly or the maximum wait time elapses.